# Card Flip hover and click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a card that can both hover and click; however, there is a minor glitch.

When the card is clicked and then hovered out from the front, the hover does not work as expected. It is flipping right back to the front. The hover is only properly implement from the back when hovered out.

what am I missing from the code to properly implement without the hover glitch?

Please help with this issue.

```js
document.querySelector(".card-flip").classList.toggle("flip");
$('.card-flip').bind({
  click: function() {
    $('.card-flip .card').toggleClass('flip');
  }
});
```

```css
.card-flip {
  -webkit-perspective: 1000px;
  perspective: 1000px;
}

.card-flip:hover .flip, .card-flip.hover .flip {
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

.card-flip,
.front,
.back {
  width: 100%;
  height: 480px;
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

.flip {
  transition: 0.6s;
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  position: relative;
}

.front,
.back {
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.front {
  z-index: 2;
  transform: rotateY(0deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(0deg);
}

.back {
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/modernizr/2.8.3/modernizr.min.js"></script>
<link rel='stylesheet' href='https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.5/css/bootstrap.min.css'>
<section style="height:40px;">&nbsp;</section>
</head>
<body>
    <section>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-6 col-lg-4">
                    <!-- Card Flip -->
                    <div class="card-flip">
                        <div class="flip">
                            <div class="front">
                                <!-- front content -->
                                <div class="card">
                                    <img class="card-img-top" data-src="holder.js/100px180/" alt="100%x180" style="height: 180px; width: 100%; display: block;" data-holder-rendered="true">
                                    <div class="card-block">
                                        <h4 class="card-title">Front Card</h4>
                                        <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
                                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="back">
                                <!-- back content -->
                                <div class="card">
                                    <div class="card-block">
                                        <h4 class="card-title">Back Card</h4>
                                        <h6 class="card-subtitle text-muted">Support card subtitle</h6>
                                    </div>
                                    <img data-src="holder.js/100px180/?text=Image" alt="Image [100%x180]" data-holder-rendered="true" style="height: 180px; width: 100%; display: block;">
                                    <div class="card-block">
                                        <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>

                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- End Card Flip -->
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
    <script src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js'></script>
    <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.3.7/js/tether.min.js'></script>
    <script src='https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.5/js/bootstrap.min.js'></script>
    <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/holder/2.9.4/holder.min.js'></script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use mouse event.

**Option 1:**

Add `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` event. (Don't rely on CSS, add/remove `flip` class on mouse events)

```js
document.querySelector(".card-flip").classList.toggle("flip");
$('.card-flip').bind({
  click: function() {
    $('.card-flip .flip').toggleClass('flip-hover');
  },
  mouseenter: function() {
    $('.card-flip .flip').addClass('flip-hover');
  },
  mouseleave: function() {
    $('.card-flip .flip').removeClass('flip-hover');
  }
});
```

```css
.card-flip {
  -webkit-perspective: 1000px;
  perspective: 1000px;
}

.card-flip .flip-hover {
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

.card-flip,
.front,
.back {
  width: 100%;
  height: 480px;
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

.flip {
  transition: 0.6s;
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  position: relative;
}

.front,
.back {
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.front {
  z-index: 2;
  transform: rotateY(0deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(0deg);
}

.back {
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/modernizr/2.8.3/modernizr.min.js"></script>
<link rel='stylesheet' href='https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.5/css/bootstrap.min.css'>
<section style="height:40px;">&nbsp;</section>
</head>
<body>
    <section>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-6 col-lg-4">
                    <!-- Card Flip -->
                    <div class="card-flip">
                        <div class="flip">
                            <div class="front">
                                <!-- front content -->
                                <div class="card">
                                    <img class="card-img-top" data-src="holder.js/100px180/" alt="100%x180" style="height: 180px; width: 100%; display: block;" data-holder-rendered="true">
                                    <div class="card-block">
                                        <h4 class="card-title">Front Card</h4>
                                        <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
                                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="back">
                                <!-- back content -->
                                <div class="card">
                                    <div class="card-block">
                                        <h4 class="card-title">Back Card</h4>
                                        <h6 class="card-subtitle text-muted">Support card subtitle</h6>
                                    </div>
                                    <img data-src="holder.js/100px180/?text=Image" alt="Image [100%x180]" data-holder-rendered="true" style="height: 180px; width: 100%; display: block;">
                                    <div class="card-block">
                                        <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>

                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- End Card Flip -->
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
    <script src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js'></script>
    <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.3.7/js/tether.min.js'></script>
    <script src='https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.5/js/bootstrap.min.js'></script>
    <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/holder/2.9.4/holder.min.js'></script>
</body>
```

Here is a fiddle. https://jsfiddle.net/nimittshah/gjhcwvk8/

**Option 2:**

If you want to keep `hover` in CSS, you will still need `mouseenter` event. (add `flip` class on `mouseenter`)

```js
//document.querySelector(".card-flip").classList.toggle("flip");
$('.card-flip').bind({
  click: function() {
    $('.card-flip .flip-me').removeClass('flip');
  },
  mouseenter: function(){
    $('.card-flip .flip-me').addClass('flip');
  }
});
```

```css
.card-flip {
  -webkit-perspective: 1000px;
  perspective: 1000px;
  transform: rotateY(0deg);
}

.card-flip:hover .flip, .card-flip.hover .flip {
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

.card-flip,
.front,
.back {
  width: 100%;
  height: 480px;
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

.flip-me {
  transition: 0.6s;
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  position: relative;
}

.front,
.back {
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.front {
  z-index: 2;
  transform: rotateY(0deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(0deg);
}

.back {
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/modernizr/2.8.3/modernizr.min.js"></script>
<link rel='stylesheet' href='https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.5/css/bootstrap.min.css'>
<section style="height:40px;">&nbsp;</section>
</head>
<body>
    <section>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-6 col-lg-4">
                    <!-- Card Flip -->
                    <div class="card-flip">
                        <div class="flip-me flip">
                            <div class="front">
                                <!-- front content -->
                                <div class="card">
                                    <img class="card-img-top" data-src="holder.js/100px180/" alt="100%x180" style="height: 180px; width: 100%; display: block;" data-holder-rendered="true">
                                    <div class="card-block">
                                        <h4 class="card-title">Front Card</h4>
                                        <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
                                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="back">
                                <!-- back content -->
                                <div class="card">
                                    <div class="card-block">
                                        <h4 class="card-title">Back Card</h4>
                                        <h6 class="card-subtitle text-muted">Support card subtitle</h6>
                                    </div>
                                    <img data-src="holder.js/100px180/?text=Image" alt="Image [100%x180]" data-holder-rendered="true" style="height: 180px; width: 100%; display: block;">
                                    <div class="card-block">
                                        <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>

                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- End Card Flip -->
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
    <script src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js'></script>
    <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.3.7/js/tether.min.js'></script>
    <script src='https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.5/js/bootstrap.min.js'></script>
    <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/holder/2.9.4/holder.min.js'></script>
</body>
```

Check fiddle. https://jsfiddle.net/nimittshah/gjhcwvk8/1/

FYI, I have added new class `flip-me` on `flip` class.

:)